# Adding a line break in Chart.js (2.7.2) labels section

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am populating the labels array with data from my API.

```
var chartData = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [{
        yAxisID: 'Seconds',
        label: 'Min',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(139, 0, 0)',
        data: []
    }, {
        label: 'Avg',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(34,139,34)',
        data: []
    }, {
        label: 'Max',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,165,0)',
        data: []
    }]
};
```

Here is my JS:

```
initJobHealth()
    .then(function(data){
        data.map(function (job) {
            var avg = job.job_duration_avg / 1000;
            avg = avg.toFixed(2);
            var max = job.job_duration_max / 1000;
            max = max.toFixed(2);
            var min = job.job_duration_min / 1000;
            min = min.toFixed(2);
            var sampleS = job.jobs_sample_size;
            var br = document.createElement("BR");
            chartData.labels.push(job.job_type + br + 'Sample Size ' + sampleS );
            chartData.datasets[0].data.push(min);
            chartData.datasets[1].data.push(avg);
            chartData.datasets[2].data.push(max);
        })
    })
    .then(initChart)
```

The goal is to insert a line break in the chartData.labels.push section between job.job_type and Sample Size string. When I insert var br in between the two and view the output on my localhost instead of getting a line break I get
 [object HTMLBRElement]

[This is where I want sampleS to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhpyJ.png)

[Data for job.job_type && SampleS = jobs_sample_size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5w8O6.png)

View when adding var br into chartData.labels.push section
[view when adding var br](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nUtm.png)

View when editing code to chartData.labels.push(job.job_type + br.outerHTML + 'Sample Size ' + sampleS );
[View when editing code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ns4qA.png)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the error with this question. Else it is very hard to help you

Answer (score 0):

It is because you add the object to a String. A solution could be

```
chartData.labels.push(job.job_type + '<br>Sample Size ' + sampleS );
```

or

```
chartData.labels.push(job.job_type + br.outerHTML + 'Sample Size ' + sampleS );
```

Comment: Both of those options gave me the same output of "job type" <br> "sample size> I have a picture but I am not sure where to post it.

Comment: @LukeReagan what is the value of job.job_type and what is the value of sampleS?

Comment: job.job_type and sampleS are Json from an API.

Comment: @LukeReagan then they are objects. You need to put there a String. If you do not give me an example, then I can not help you further.

Comment: I added some new pictures that may help my question make more sense.